# While performing Ubuntu Install and running LiveCd my PC experiences random power cycles

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, crash

I've tried many different types of installs and running of Ubuntu LiveCd, all end with a power cycle within a few minutes at random points in time.  The computer never hangs or locks up.  The power turns off, then the computer turns back on.

The computer works fine with Windows 10.  Has never randomly shutdown.

I've tried Ubuntu 18.04.1, 18.04.4 and 20.04.

This same problem occurs on 2 different PCs that are identical.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 running on the same computer, only 1 year older. The only difference is these new ones has a semi-modular power supply.

I've tried booting from DVD and from USB stick.
I've tried booting with nomodeset.
I've tried booting with and without a network connection.
I've tried booting with CSM off.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?
How to log system messages to determine what the problem is?
Once the power turns off, how can I see the system logs?

System is DuroPC R150-114 4U 8th Gen Core I7 With 8 PCI, 1x PCIex16, 3x PCIex1.
Chipset: Intel Q370
Memory: 32 GB DDR4

I just tried 'noapic' option, and the computer restarted in the middle of the install process.
I've also tried the 'nomodeset' option with no success.
Not sure how to set the 'irqpoll' option as suggested by @KGIII , it is not in the F6 option list.

Thanks.

Comment: Knowing computer make and model helps.  Google not showing any problems with semi-modular power supply with ubuntu.  Think newer computer not as similar to older one as you think

Comment: In addition to the info that @crip659 wants, have you tried the advanced option and used 'noapic'? If not, maybe 'irqpoll' but I haven't had to toggle that in a long, long time.